# Save and close workbook without prompting after running a macro?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I want to save and close the Excel file in which I am executing a macro (Module : modBex, Sub: Test) via VBScript.

The following code is working fine, except the Excel file (`macro_file.xlsm`) doesn't get saved.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\macro_file.xlsm", 0, True)
xlApp.Run "modBex.Test"
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlBook.Save
xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlAddin = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Why do you have `DisplayAlerts = False` in there? What message were you getting? I don't see how the book could not be saved when you save it explicitly.

Comment: Are you sure your code run entirely and not break somewhere? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Set `xlApp.Visible = True` and `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True`, so you can see what's going on.

Comment: also make sure you do not have any strange line commands inside "modBex.Test" for example "End" wich will terminate the process prematurely. Also try closing the workbook and then exiting the application. xlBook.close true

Answer (score 2):

Change the line

```
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\macro_file.xlsm", 0, True)
```

to

```
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\macro_file.xlsm", 0, False)
```

as I believe that flag is setting the file to open as Read Only, leading to an error when saving the document.

In addition to this, if you leave any and all alert suppressing (ie `.DisplayAlerts = False`)until you know you have working code, then it makes things like this easier to spot.

Comment: Thanks mate, so dumb of me ^^